# TCPDF how to set two text color?

Tags: php, tcpdf

Currently I am trying to customize the whmcs invoice pdf. They have this following code

```
    # Payment Status
$endpage = $pdf->GetPage();
$pdf->setPage($startpage);
$pdf->SetXY(85,$addressypos);
if ($status=="Cancelled") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicescancelled"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(245,245,245);
} elseif ($status=="Unpaid") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicesunpaid"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(204,0,0);
} elseif ($status=="Paid") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicespaid"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(153,204,0);
} elseif ($status=="Refunded") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicesrefunded"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(34,68,136);
} elseif ($status=="Collections") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicescollections"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,204,0);
}
$pdf->SetFont('freesans','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(110,20,strtoupper($statustext),0,0,'C');
$pdf->setPage($endpage);

?>
```

This code produce this format,

For example, if paymenet is "Unpaid", code produce this echo statement

> UNPAID (with red color)

so what I am trying to do is, I would like to add this text "Status:" infront of "UNPAID" so for example, when echo out, it will become like this

> "Status: UNPAID"

I can get it by adding this code

```
} elseif ($status=="Unpaid") {
        $statustext = $_LANG["statustext"];
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicesunpaid"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(245,245,245);
```

But because of this code

```
$pdf->SetTextColor(245,245,245);
```

Status: becomes (Red) as well.

What can I achieve to get Status: text black and UNPAID remained as "RED".

Please kindly point me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I have achieved different texts  with setting the text color before I need to write something with: $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);

Here is an example of my code: 
(the actual text being written is outside of this if statement, but I change the backgroung of the text and therefore I need to change the text color to be visible )

```
    if ($row_cnt > ($sticker_count / 2)) {
        $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
        $pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/sticker_29072013.svg', $xsi, $ysi, $w='60', $h='30', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border, $fitonpage=false);
        $pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/qr_29072013.svg', $xqi, $yqi, $w='30', $h='30', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border, $fitonpage=false);
    }
    else {
        $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
        $pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/blacksticker_29072013.svg', $xsi, $ysi, $w='60', $h='30', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border, $fitonpage=false);
        $pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/blackqr_29072013.svg', $xqi, $yqi, $w='30', $h='30', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border, $fitonpage=false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this replacing `$pdf->Cell` with `$pdf->writeHTMLCell` so the source will be like this:

```
} elseif ($status=="Unpaid") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["statustext"];
    $statustext .= "<font color=red>".$_LANG["invoicesunpaid"]."</font>";
...
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(110, 20, '', '', $statustext , 1, 1, 1, true, 'J', true);
```

And [here](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8458280d15b73d3baffb28eebe2d9246) is the doc for that function. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for you:

1) Output both words **in separate Cells**, i.e. first "Status:" then "UNPAID". Like this:

```
$endpage = $pdf->GetPage();
$pdf->setPage($startpage);
$pdf->SetXY(85,$addressypos);
$pdf->SetFont('freesans','B',12);

// First output "Status:" in black color.
$pdf->setTextColor( array(0,0,0) );
$pdf->Cell(110,20,'Status:',0,0,'L'); // Not centered anymore!

// Now run your existing condition to get the status text/color:
if ($status=="Cancelled") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicescancelled"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(245,245,245);
} elseif ($status=="Unpaid") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicesunpaid"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(204,0,0);
} elseif ($status=="Paid") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicespaid"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(153,204,0);
} elseif ($status=="Refunded") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicesrefunded"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(34,68,136);
} elseif ($status=="Collections") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicescollections"];
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,204,0);
}

// Output the status text at X = 125 (1.5cm further to the right!)
// Note that the word "Status" above used X = 110. 
$pdf->Cell(125,20,strtoupper($statustext),0,0,'L'); // Not centered anymore!
$pdf->setPage($endpage);
```

2) Use **HTML markup** and writeHTMLCell() to output the text:

```
$endpage = $pdf->GetPage();
$pdf->setPage($startpage);
$pdf->SetXY(85,$addressypos);
$pdf->SetFont('freesans','B',12);

// Now run your existing condition to get the status text/color:
if ($status=="Cancelled") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicescancelled"];
    $color = 'rgb(245,245,245)';
} elseif ($status=="Unpaid") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicesunpaid"];
    $color = 'rgb(204,0,0)';
} elseif ($status=="Paid") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicespaid"];
    $color = 'rgb(153,204,0)';
} elseif ($status=="Refunded") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicesrefunded"];
    $color = 'rgb(34,68,136)';
} elseif ($status=="Collections") {
    $statustext = $_LANG["invoicescollections"];
    $color = 'rgb(255,204,0)';
}

// Now build an HTML string for the status:
$html = '<font color="black">Status:</font> '.
    '<font style="color:$color">$statustext</font>';

// Output the HTML code
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(110,20,0,0,$html); 
$pdf->setPage($endpage);
```